# Calculating standard deviation from a set of data

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm trying to create a normal distribution of numbers between 0 and 100.
I know that the mean = 28, and the only other information about the data is that
there is a 10 % change that the number is 44, and a 1 % chance of it being 74.
Other then that it should be distributed around the mean.

So my question is how do I calculate the standard deviation based on this?

Thanks in advance!

edit: chance**

Comment: The normal distribution is continuous, so the probability that x=44 is zero, as it is for any other specific value. Do you mean $P(x>=44)=0.1$ and $P(x>=74)=0.01$?

Comment: That would be a much better way to put it, yes!

Comment: By the word *change*, did you perhaps mean the word *CHANCE* instead?  =)

Comment: That is correct sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a normal distribution table (or the calculator equivalent) to determine the z-score associated with 99%, that is, $P(z<Z)=0.99$ means $P(z>Z)=0.01$. Then solve $Z=(74-28)/\sigma$ for $\sigma$.